# Problemas al insertar varios datos en un campo

Tags: python, django

Estoy realizando una aplicación la cual asigna a un desarrollador una tarea y esa tarea tiene varias actividades.

Ejemplo tarea de realizar una app social y las actividades podrian ser:

- login
- graficos
- correo, etc.

El problema es que **no encuentro la forma de asignar multiples actividades a una tarea**. Intenté el modelo de muchos a muchos de con tabla intermedia pero no me funciono, luego el muchos a muchos de forma tradicional, y tampoco.

Este es mi modelo de muchos a muchos de forma tradicional

```
class Task(models.Model):
    developer = models.ManyToManyField(Developer)
    type_task = models.ForeignKey(TypeTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    state = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Activities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    task = models.ManyToManyField(Task)
```

Y esta es mi vista:

```
class TaskCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'users:login'
    permission_required = 'tasks.can_add_user'
    template_name = 'tasks/add_task.html'
    form_class = TaskForm
    model = Task
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks:task')
```

Agradezco la ayuda.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tus modelos te aconsejo utilizar `TimeStampedModel` ya trae el created y updated integrado y puedes acortar las lineas de tu codigo

```
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel

class Task(TimeStampedModel):
    developer = models.ManyToManyField(Activities)
    type_task = models.ForeignKey(TypeTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    state = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True)



class Activities(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Si intentas colocar `ManyToMany` en los 2 modelos te va a salir un error ya que sera una relación circular, aunque en actividades no tenias declarado el created y updated te aconsejo que uses en todos tus modelos el `TimeStampedModel` ya que son campos de control para tu proyecto y para la base de datos.

En la vista para que no te cause algún problema podrías utilizar un formview con form_valid

Ya que no colocaste tus forms intentare colocar el código lo mas sencillo para que puedas darte una idea y puedas adaptarlo a tu vista

```
class TaskFormView(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    login_url = 'users:login'
    permission_required = 'tasks.can_add_user'
    template_name = 'tasks/add_task.html'
    form_class = TaskForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks:task')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        type_task = form.cleaned_data['type_task']
        task = form.cleaned_data['task']
        description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        state = form.cleaned_data['state']
        slug = form.cleaned_data['slug']
        obj, created = Task.objects.get_or_create(
            type_task = type_task
            task = task
            description = description
            state = state
            slug = slug

        )
        for item in developer:
            obj.developer.add(item)
        return super(TaskFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Ya que no se si el `slug` lo colocas como un campo en el tus forms lo coloque en el `form valid` pero si no lo usas solo lo quitas.

Para que te reconozca un parámetro `ManyToMany` lo tienes que ciclar con el `for` del final si no te saldrá un error.

Suerte

Comment: el modelo TimeStampedModel no tenia idea te que existiera gracias, pero quitaste la relacion que hay entre el modelo task y developer bueno eso se arregla, lo otro es que la forma en que me suguieres fue la primera forma en que lo intente y esta forma no es practica para el usuario pues tendria que creer primero las actividades en el modelo actividades y despues asignarlas al modelo tareas

Comment: y esto seria un inconveniente pues para crear las las actividades primero se necesita tener una tarea, y lo que necesito es que cuando se este asignando o creando una tarea a un desarrollador las actividades se vayan creando en el mismo formulario, lo intente con ajax creando un arreglo y despues asignandoselo al campo pero me generaba error

Comment: por eso queria saber que consojos me podrian dar para realizar esta actividad de mejor forma, pues primera vez que mi encuentro con este punto y no se como realizarlo de forma optima o mas bien practica para el usuario final o cliente

Comment: Te aconsejaría leer la normalización de base de datos https://ed.team/blog/normalizacion-de-bases-de-datos ya que se debe de realizar tablas independientes para conjuntos de valores que se apliquen a varios registros, es por buena practica y ademas es como se debe de realizar para evitar problemas en el futuro.

Comment: Si es un proyecto propio puede que no se vea mucho el cambio aunque te ahorraras muchos problemas futuros pero ya en una empresa donde haya un DBA pedirán la normalización y seria mejor irse acostumbrando.

Comment: Si por eso puse que ya habia intentado con una tabla intermedia, pero no he podido agregar varios campos